# WebGL & Google's Chrome Frame - dropping support for IE

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, webgl, google-chrome-frame

If you want to do browser-based 3D rendering, WebGL looks great but simply isn't supported in IE. Since the only other real option for browser-based 3D is to use a plugin, then it seems like Chrome Frame is a viable alternative... IE users still have to install the plugin/addon/extension but other users on FF/Chrome do not need to.

In a corporate environment we might expect installing browser-addons to be hard to get permission for... but as I say on IE you're going to *have* to install some sort of plugin regardless, whether it's generic like Chrome Frame or specific like Unity3D or your own bespoke plugin.

Does this seem reasonable, that we can simply drop IE support for this kind of specialist app and let Chrome Frame automatically run on IE when needed?

Comment: I miss a question here, what do you want to know?

Comment: if this is a reasonable decision, or if there are technical factors regarding Chrome Frame (or other things) I haven't seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebGL is still relatively new, and your options are not clearcut.  If you are willing to wait, Flash will also support hardware accelerated 3D, but that is still [in development](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplatformruntimes/incubator/features/molehill.html).

There is early talk of building IE Webgl shims using Flash, which would be an alternative to Chrome Frame.

Also, depending on how intensive your 3D rendering needs are, you might be able to get away with a 3D framework like [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/), which will fall back to SVG or canvas if WebGL is not available.

Comment: If it's not using hardware rendering it's not of interest... that means shaders and everything. Right now Flash doesn't seem anywhere near good enough, whereas WebGL basically just gives you a JS wrapper around OpenGL (if I understood right).

Comment: @John, It's a wrapper around OpenGL ES 2.0, which is a subset of OpenGL.  Sort of good, because it's a minimal subset.  But it makes getting to "hello triangle" more complicated than old-school GL.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference between Chrome Frame and Flash.  One is supported by Microsoft and the IE team.  You will encounter less resistance to [Flash](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2011/02/flash-player-10-2-launch.html).

If you're in a corporate environment and you need your users to run Chrome for some specific thing, then deploy Chrome and have them run it.

Comment: I'm not sure that is always a valid option, even if it is it's less user-friendly if they have to remember to open the right browser for the page wanted. However official support for plugins by MS is a relevant point... except on IE6 perhaps which even MS don't want to support!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use JebGL until IE supports WebGL natively. JebGL is a Java-based fallback in early development. You can check it out at http://jebgl.googlecode.com